# wordpress video settings- unable to resize video in smaller screen

Tags: wordpress, video, resize

I have uploaded a youtube video on my wordpress site. It displays fine on full screen, but when I change the screen to mobile size, the video does not shrink and still shows bigger screen size. I am new to wordpress and not sure how to proceed.
Here is the link: http://demo.repair8pp.com